# Laravel Development blogs

Tags: php, laravel

```
//category model
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table="category";
        protected $fillable = [
        'CategoryName','Description','status'
        ];

}

//Blog model
class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $table="blog";
    protected $fillable = [
        'BlogTitle','Description','status','filepath','category','comments','rfilepath'
    ];

}

//controller
$blogs = Blog::Where('status','=','active')->get();

return View::make("categories.viewblog")->with("blogs", $blogs);
```

I can get only active blogs in the view section but i need if my category is inactive the category should not be viewed in the view section or vice versa. 
I think making relationships would be correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use eloquent relations

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table="category";
        protected $fillable = [
        'CategoryName','Description','status'
        ];

    function blogs(){
        return $this->hasMany(Blog::class);
    }

}

//Blog model
class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $table="blog";
    protected $fillable = [
        'BlogTitle','Description','status','filepath','category','comments','rfilepath'
    ];

   function category(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
   }

}
```

now get the active categories

```
$categories = Category::Where('status','=','active')->get();
```

and then

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
     @foreach($category->blogs as $blog)
          {{ $blog->BlogTitle }}
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```